# Representation variety vs. space of flat connections

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, principal-bundles, gauge-theory, holonomy, character-varieties

The holonomy provides a bijection from

- the space of flat $G$-connections (modulo gauge equivalence) on a trivial $G$-bundle over $M$

to

- a connected component of the representation variety $Hom(\pi_1M,G)/G$.

Is this a homeomorphism for the $C^\infty$-topology on the space of connections?

If not, what can be said? Does it preserve path components?

Comment: The holonomy does not provide such a bijection. It only provides a bijection between the space of flat connections on the trivial bundle and a connected component of of the representation variety. Often the representation variety will have more components. If $M$ is a compact manifold and $G$ is a complex reductive group, then this bijection is a homeomorphism. In fact if $M$ is a complex projective algebraic variety, the bijection is a complex analytic isomorphism.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Does one really need the bundle to be trivial? Doesn't it work in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, the bijection between the Betti moduli space and the de Rham moduli space is a homeomorphism.

See [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5025v1.pdf) for a nice exposition on this topic with references for further reading.